# How to skip a file when scanning files in a directory

Tags: c

I have a program that list all the files in a directory. If a file is broken link, I am wanting to skip that file and continue scanning other files in a file. I would highly appreciate if someone can point where I am wrong. Following is  part of my code

```
d = opendir(".");
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {

 char buff[256];
 int target = readlink (dir->d_name, buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (target == -1)
    {
        printf("i found broken link  so continuing to next file..\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is, it is printing following while I only have one broken link

```
i found broken link  so continuing to next file
i found broken link  so continuing to next file
i found broken link  so continuing to next file
```

and goes on until the last file.

Comment: `... On error, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error....` -->> `EINVAL The named file is not a symbolic link.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question should have some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) & [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html). Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer.

Consider using [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) or [fts(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) (if you need to scan the subdirectories recursively) or at least do a [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) with the file path (since you are scanning the current directory, you don't need to construct that file path).  Remember to skip the entries for `.` and `..`; so try perhaps

```
 d = opendir(".");
 while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
   struct stat mystat;
   if (!strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir->d_name, "..")) continue;
   memset (&mystat, 0, sizeof(mystat));
   if (stat(dir->d_name, &mystat) ||  S_ISLNK(mystat.st_mode))
     continue;
   /// etc...
 }
```

There are many cases that you might want to handle. See also [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). What about a symlink to self? What about [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets? [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s? permissions?

(We don't have time and space to explain all the details; you do need to read a lot)

Comment: Please don't just point people at a bunch of manpages, manpages often only make sense if you have already internalized how to read them.  Also, please recommend `fts` instead of `nftw`, as `nftw` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, and also may not support very large directories.

Comment: @zwol: [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) most definitely supports very large directories. The GNU C library implementation is known to be thread-safe, unless one of the functions (or another thread) changes the current working directory (`nftw()` itself does not change it). POSIX.1 does not guarantee it. `nftw()` does not need a descriptor per depth; it only uses *up to* one per depth. Plus, it is POSIX.1-2008, whereas `fts` is BSD-specific (but happens to be supported by GNU C library).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you have

```
d = opendir(dirname);
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    some_operation(dir->d_name);
}
```

`some_operation` will fail for *every* `d_name`, because the path you should have passed to `some_operation` is `${dirname}/${dir->d_name}`, not just `dir->d_name`.

Your program, though, is hardwired to pass the special directory `.` to `opendir`; when you do that, it *is* safe to pass just `dir->d_name` to `some_operation`, since `.` is always the current working directory.  Your problem is instead that `readlink` *does not* fail when applied to a broken symlink, but *does* fail when applied to a directory entry that isn't a symlink.  It would have been easier to figure this out for yourself if you had included `dir->d_name` and `strerror(errno)` in your error message, like this:

```
d = opendir(".");
while ((dir = readdir(d)) != 0) {
   char buff[256];
   if (readlink(dir->d_name, buff, sizeof buff) {
       printf("%s: readlink failed: %s\n", dir->d_name, strerror(errno));
   } else {
       printf("%s -> %s\n", dir->d_name, buff);
   }
}
```

If you had done that, you would have gotten output like this:

```
.gnome2: readlink failed: Invalid argument
.python_history: readlink failed: Invalid argument
test.s: readlink failed: Invalid argument
bin -> .local/bin
[etc]
```

and then it would probably have occurred to you to look at the `readlink` manpage and discover that it returns `EINVAL` when applied to something that isn't a symlink.

The proper way to detect a broken symlink is by observing that `lstat` succeeds but `stat` fails with `ENOENT`:

```
struct stat lst, st;
if (lstat(dir->d_name, &lst)) {
  /* some other kind of problem */
} else if (!S_ISLNK(lst.st_mode)) {
  /* not a symlink at all */
} else if (stat(dir->d_name, &st)) {
  if (errno == ENOENT) {
    /* broken symlink */
  } else {
    /* some other kind of problem */
  }
} else {
  /* valid symlink, `lst` tells you about the link,
     `st` tells you about what it points to */
}
```

If you don't need any of the other information from `lst`, and your filesystem supports `d_type`, you can skip the `lstat` call:

```
if (dir->d_type == DT_LNK) {
   struct stat st;
   if (stat(dir->d_name, &st)) {
     if (errno == ENOENT) {
       /* broken symlink */
     }
   }
 }
```

But don't neglect to do the entire dance with both `lstat` and `stat` in the `DT_UNKNOWN` case, or you'll be sad when you try to run your program on a filesystem that doesn't report d_type information.